# Segfault cs50 pset4 recover

Tags: c, cs50

I'm always getting a segfault when trying to run the code.
I think it is caused by the last lines fclose(file) and fclose(img), but I don't really seem to understand why exactly.
If I delete both lines nothing happens.
Could someone please explain to me why segfault is called and why it is not creating new .jpg's?

(I have to implement a program that recovers JPEGs from a forensic image)
https://cs50.harvard.edu/college/2020/fall/psets/4/recover/

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cs50.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //open file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    //promting user
    if(argc != 2)
    {
    printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
    return 1;
    }
    else if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty file.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int found = 0;
    unsigned char buffer[512];
    FILE *img = NULL;


    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, file))
    {
        //start of new Jpeg?
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xff && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            //close file if found
            if(found == 1)
            {
                fclose(img);
            }

            // open new one
            else
            {
                found = 1;
            }

            char filename[8];
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            i++;

        }

        if(found == 1)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
        }


    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(img);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just a side note: Check `argc` before you access `argv`!

Comment: What happens if you do not find any JPEG header in the file at all?

Comment: Why don't you write the first block to file? `if(found == 1) { fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img); }` Make it unconditional.

Comment: `img = fopen(filename, "w");` If the `fopen` fails then `img` will be NULL and you will (probably) segfault when trying to write or close it.

Comment: Anyhow, there are lots of debugging tools that will help you determine for yourself where the segfault occurs, instead of having to ask other people.  Debugging is an essential part of programming and so now you get to learn about it.

Comment: Note, if you can make your [mre] without the cs50 header, you could reach a much larger audience of helpfully minded StackOverflow users.